# How to use elemMatch

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hello my mongoose schema like this

```
    const mongoose =  require("mongoose")
const Rooms = new mongoose.Schema({
  createdBy : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  Roomname : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  createdDate : {
    type : Date,
    default : Date.now
  },
  Message : [{
    username : String,
    date :  Date
  }],
  wants : [{
    username : String,
    message : String,
    status : {type : Boolean,default : false},
    date : {type : Date,default:Date.now}

  }]
})

const rooms = mongoose.model("Rooms",Rooms)
module.exports = rooms
```

router.js like this

```
   router.put("/accesswant",async(req,res) => {
  try{ 

    rooms.findByIdAndUpdate({
    _id : req.body.id,
    wants : {'elemMatch' : {id : req.body.roomid}}
  },{

    $pull : {
      wants : [{
        status : true
      }]
    }
  },{new : true}.exec((err,result) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      res.status(201).send(result)
    }
  })
  )
```

I want to update a directory that I specified in the wants object array in a specified collection. How can I do? I did some research and I found elemMatch but I guess I can't use it.

For those who do not understand, for example:

Inside the collection with id: 60625a30290f2d4ec8928eb4
Under the `` wants '' directory:
update the value with id: 60625fef715045586e292f

Comment: You need to post a sample document to understand what you are trying to tell.

Comment: There's no id reference in wants and you are matching id

Answer (score 0):

You are trying something like this I believe you need type of objectId in array of wants.

```
var exampleSchema = new Schema({
   listOfIds: [{ myId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'someObj' }],
});

var Example = mongoose.model('gh2799', exampleSchema);
Example.findOne({ listOfIds: { $elemMatch: { myId: 'ObjectId('euii4rh93jd984fho') } } }, function(err) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  console.log('success');
  process.exit(0);
});
```